# Testing Neptune (Graph DB) Locally

Tags: amazon-neptune

I have already found the "Request Preview" [page](https://pages.awscloud.com/NeptunePreview.html), apart from that is there any way to deploy and test Neptune locally?

Comment: I suppose AWS Neptune is based on [tag:Blazegraph].

Comment: are you using the RDF/SPARQL interface, or the Gremlin interface?

Comment: Gremlin to commect5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Neptune can be tested only from within the VPC. What you can probably do is
1. Create an ec2 instance in the same VPC
2. Install Gremlin/ SPARQL console in ec2 (if you need to execute queries)
3. connect to Neptune via ec2
4. Execute queries

Neptune DB can be either SPARQL/ Gremlin. It is based on the first query you hit.

If SPARQL, metaphacts can be used for the visual representation of the database.

Comment: any free Neptune testing is available online? didnt find any

Comment: you need to be whitelisted in order to avail testing Neptune. please follow this page:  
https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/

Comment: neptune is available for testing only for whitelisted customers. Maybe you can follow the instructions and send them mail. Not much of a hurdle!!

Comment: Neptune is GA as of June 2018, so you should not need any white-listing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Neptune is Generally Available in 4 regions as of June 2018 and you should be able to create instances on your own without requiring any white-listing. You can use some of the [cloud formation examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) to get a test setup created in minutes. There is no other way to test Neptune unfortunately.